# Change content without page reload [Bootstrap 5]

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm learning Bootstrap 5, now i saw that it is possible with navs that we can change the content within a div. Now i want to change the content when clicking on a card from div1 to div2 I know it's possible with JavaScript but the question is to make it work with Bootstrap classes only!

```
<div>
      <div>
           <a href="#div2">Card</a>
      </div>
</div>

<main class="main">
     <div class="container h-100">
          <div class="div1">Show as default</div>
          <div class="div2">Show on card click! And hide div1</div>
     </div>
</main>
```

I tried to check with AI, checked the bootstrap docs.

I want to show and hide divs inside another container to show and hide (replace) content based on the clicks in another div

Comment: You would need some radio input shenanigans to make this work without any Javascript. And this would require CSS, no bootstrap class can make you do it magically. HTML is STATIC, and bootstrap is just classes inside HTML. You most likely need Javascript.

Comment: @Salketer, so i need to make a nav to make this work as i want example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hqwafetx/

Comment: is this you looking for [collapse navs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/)?

Comment: @francisco not really i have a card divs that whenever 1 is clicked that the main changes into another div with a input and messages etc.
See img https://ibb.co/j59yLCq

Answer (score -1):

Hi^ i dont test it with boostrap^ but i think this will be work

i resize label for check box by parent container and hide checkbox and by checked selector hide div and reverse

I hope it helped

P.S. link to codepen `https://codepen.io/imabramon/pen/QWYeQrB`
P.S.P.S. now it replace by link

```css
.checkbox{
  display:none;
}

.label{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.label-container{
  position: relative;
}

.div1:has(+ .checkbox:checked){
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:not(:checked) + .div2{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
      <div class="label-container">
           <a href="#div2">Card</a>
          <label for="checkbox" class="label"></label>
      </div>
</div>

<main class="main">
  
     <div class="container h-100">
          <div class="div1">Show as default</div>
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
          <div class="div2">Show on card click! And hide div1</div>
       
       
     </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I rather want to avoid a hidden checkbox.
This is my current example code https://jsfiddle.net/rfyujb0v/
This is the example how it currently showed as image https://ibb.co/j59yLCq